# How to filter last 5 minutes, date histogram using Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, date-range

using Elasticsearch 1.1.1

I'm trying to build a query of "page" views per second for the last 5 minutes for all accounts (so match all).

The mapping is...

```
"xxx-20140526": {
    "mappings": {
      "xxx": {
        "properties": {
          "accountId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hitTime": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The query...

```
POST /xxx-20140526/xxx/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "timeHit": {
        "gte": "2014-05-26T13:40", //Date generated dynamically now - 5mins
        "lt": "2014-05-26T13:45" //Date generated dynamically now
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "views_per_sec": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timeHit",
        "interval": "second"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the aggregation also returns values from previous times...

```
"aggregations": {
    "trx_per_sec": {
        "buckets": [
        {
            "key_as_string": "2014-05-26T13:36:46.000Z",
            "key": 1401111166000,
            "doc_count": 72
        },
        ... Other dates in the 30 mins range here...
        {
           "key_as_string": "2014-05-26T13:42:47.000Z",
           "key": 1401111167000,
           "doc_count": 5013
        }
     }
}
```

1- Do aggregations consider the filter?
2- Is it the right way to filter for the last 5 minutes or should I look at date aggregations?

I also tried...

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "timeHit",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "now-5m"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to return the right amount of docs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok so I got it working here is the query...

```
{
  "size": 0, <--- Size zero. Don't return any docs we only care about the aggregation.
  "aggs": {
    "last_5_mins": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "hitTime": {
            "gte": "now-5m",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tps": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "hitTime",
            "interval": "second"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```